# How to prevent from "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIPickerView._backgroundView symbol not found" error?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to access _backgroundView variable declared as @private in the header  UIPickerView.h, using categories.
As result linker retun an error "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIPickerView._backgroundView ..... symbol(s) not found".
Attempts to use linker options such as -all_load, -ObjC have no any result.

There are any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: No, there is not, because the ivar is private and thus does not exist to you.  It exists ONLY to the UIKit engineers and you should NOT try to much around with.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't do it. It's private for a reason.
2. If you must do it, you could try using `[pickerView valueForKey:@"_backgroundView"]`. Don't submit this to the App Store.