# Error [IRForTarget]: Couldn't find Objective-C indirect ivar symbol while adding overlays to MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay, ivar

I got this error when I'm trying to add overlays to map, from one of SO answers [How to prevent from "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIPickerView._backgroundView symbol not found" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217038/how-to-prevent-from-objc-ivar-uipickerview-backgroundview-symbol-not-found) I understood that we shouldn't use private ivar, but i didn't use any of them in my code, still I got the following error.

**Error [IRForTarget]: Couldn't find Objective-C indirect ivar symbol OBJC_IVAR_$_MKPolygon._interiorPolygons**

Please show me the way to solve this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983192/weird-error-message-in-xcode-4-3-with-lldb

Comment: I make the modifications to my code as mentioned in the above link, but no use..

Answer (score 0):

As of XCode 4.5 the 3 variable declaration statements can be collapsed into 1

1. An iVar
2. A Property
3. A Synthesize

Now:
1. Synthesize

So, if old code was:

```
NSString* name; //in .h file
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name; // in .h file
@synthesize name; // in .m file
```

Since 4.5 this is all that is needed is:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name; // in .h file
```

We can now address this iVar with either of the following:

```
self.name = @"john"; // used to reference the full property setter/getting - usually from outside the object
_name = @"john"; // used to reference an internal variable
```

This error message happened to me when the I used the iVar (notice no leading underscore):

```
name = @"john";
```

To fix change to either:

```
   self.name = @"john"; // or
    _name = @"john";
```

Note: I did not get this error on xcode version 4.5 (4G182) but I did on 4.5.2 (4G2008a).